# can a value of a key/value pair also be a key?

Tags: javascript, object, key

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgXIu.png)

In this example, to log the value of the properties with the keys "title" and "director", obj[key] is used. Since we're already in the execution context of the object: movie, in this example. Obj in "Obj[key]" must refer to title: 'a', and director: 'b' and key to the value of these objects, so "a" and "b" are noted as keys, right?

Can these "key-type" values also be logged with obj[value]?

---

This is an example in a course, but the instructor is not explaining it well, so I've probably spent two hours at this point trying to understand the nomenclature. I hope this is correct, and if not; I'd really appreciate whatever misstep I'm making.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably ask your instructor to explain it better.  His job is to find a way to make the concept clear.

Comment: if you try obj['a'] nothing will output since only have title,releaseYear, rating, director keys. if you try obj['title'] the value 'a' will be output.

Comment: @Robert Harvey I'm not being taught directly, I'm following a course. But I was surprised there was no option to add a comment to a lecture. Only a forum, but not one with active professionals. Or much activity anyhow. Not an ideal situation no

Answer (score 1):

Putting the code from the image here for easier reference, have also changed the logs slightly to make it clear which is the key and which is the value:

```js
const movie = {
  title: 'a',
  releaseYar: 2018,
  rating: 4.5,
  director: 'b'
};

showProperties(movie);

function showProperties(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) 
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'string') {
      console.log('key -->', key);
      console.log('value -->', obj[key]);
    }
}
```

Nope, 'a' and 'b' in that example are not keys, they are values. 
In that example, `movie` is the object. The keys of the movie object are `title`, `releaseYear`, `rating` and `director`. Key is just another name for 'property' by the way.

In the `showProperties` function, you loop through each key -- ie. at every iteration, `key` is at first `title`, then `releaseYear`, and so on. 
`obj[key]` in the first iteration would be `movie['title']`, which would give a value of `a`.

The console logs show the key, followed by the value of `movie[key]`. Hence the key of `title`, and the value of `a` for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the comment to understand the code and run code.

```js
const movie = {
  title: "SOmething",
  releaseDate: 2020,
  rating: 4.5,
  director: "Someone",
};
function showProperties(object) {
  for (const key in object) {
    const value = object[key]; // get value of the key
    console.log(key, value); // log everything
    // check if value is type string
    if (typeof value === "string") {
      console.log(key, value); // then only if value is string
    }
  }
}
showProperties(movie);
```

Comment: Thaaaank you so much.. This has been a really frustrating thing to learn, I just couldn't find the right answer anywhere.

Comment: haha!! :-D hire me.. Please accept as an answer. If it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: {edit} somehow I add blank lines without sending the comment. So here's the rest: The only thing I'm still slightly confused about is why the value of the key/ property (is key always a property actually?) is noted as object[key]. Seeing as we're already in the execution context of the object, can't it be written as [key]?

Comment: Didn't I already accept as an answer, I don't see the option anywhere anyhow

Comment: hahaha! no worries .. . regarding ur question, It is not possible to get `key by value`. Here `obj[val] !== 'key'` since here value will consider as key

Comment: Either you misunderstood my question or I'm misinterpretating your question. But if not, I'm not talking about the second example you gave, but the original example. to log the value of the key object[key] is used. What confuses me is why the object in object[key] has to be written down at all, since we're already in the execution context of object. So to get the value, instead of logging object[key]; can't we log [key] instead. Anyways, it's not a big detail. I might as well use object[key] just so it works :)